UIRotationGestureRecgnizer delegate methods not triggered
im using the DGCharts library to display a pie chart.  This chart is within a vertical scrollview, and the chart has the ability to rotate around its axis.  This works with a single swipe, however the scrollviews swipe/pan gesture gets in the way and takes over.  I would like to prevent the scollviews gesture recognizer when the chart is being rotated.
The pie chart has a UIRotationGestureRecognizer and a UITapGestureRecognizer.  Using UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods i tried
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        // Allow the rotation gesture to work alongside the scroll view's pan gesture
        if gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer || otherGestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == scrollView.panGestureRecognizer {
            // If the pan gesture recognizer is triggered and the touch is inside `yourView`, prevent the scroll view from scrolling
            let locationInView = touch.location(in: pieChartView)
            if pieChartView.bounds.contains(locationInView) {
                return false // Disable the scroll view's pan gesture when touching `yourView`
            }
        }

        // Otherwise, allow the gesture to be received as usual
        return true
    }

and i also tried scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: rotationRecognizer)
both of which are not successful.
i did set the delegate:
        if let pieViewRecognizers = pieChartView.gestureRecognizers {
            for gestureRecognizer in pieViewRecognizers {
                if gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
                    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }

Primarily the issue seems to be that UIRotationGestureRecognizer expects a two finger touch to trigger the delegate methods needed to disable the scrollview when in use, but i can swipe and rotate the chart with a single finger and id like to prevent the scrollview from taking over if a single finger swipes the chart.
What else can i try to stop the scrollview from moving around when im trying to rotate the chart?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495508/2303865

Have you set the gesture recognizer’s delegate?

@LeoDabus yes i have, i edited the post to clarify that.

if you set the scroll view's panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches to 2, does the chart rotation work? just want to make sure that it is in fact the scrollview's panGestureRecognizer is the culprit

If the scroll view's pan gesture is the reason, you can try setting its cancelsTouchesInView to false to prevent it from canceling other gestures

@SonNguyen your answer is the closest to what the problem is.  Turns out the library has a .rotationWithTwoFingers property for this specific reason.  Comments on this property state

If you want to add this as an answer ill provide you with the credit as you ultimately led me to the correct answer.

Glad that my vague comment helps you with the issue. I think you can add the answer to help others using the same lib. No need to credit me as I didn't give the correct answer.

The library has a .rotationWithTwoFingers property for this specific reason. Comments on this property state
flag that indicates if rotation is done with two fingers or one. when the chart is inside a scrollview, you need a two-finger rotation because a one-finger rotation eats up all touch events. 
